# How to know if a date is between a list of start/end dates?

Tags: excel

I have a table where I put my holidays that way:

```
| Start date | End date   | Reason                 |
+------------+------------+------------------------+
| 01/02/2018 | 15/02/2018 | Trip to somewhere nice |
| 07/04/2018 | 08/04/2018 | Sick days              |
...
```

I have another table with a list of dates

```
| Date     | Holiday? |
+----------+----------+
|03/02/2018| YES      |
|20/02/2018| NO       |
|08/04/2018| YES      |
...
```

My question: how can I write a formula in the `Holiday?` column to know if I was on holiday on the date on the left? All the dates are in the Date type.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `countifs`

to count if the date in the lefthand `$B$3:$B$4` column is less than or equal to the date you want to check `B9` and count it the date in the righthand column `$C$3:$C$4` is greater than or equal to the test date `B9`.

`=COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$4,"<="&B9,$C$3:$C$4,">="&B9)`

this returns 0 if it's not within any of the dates or 1,2,3.. if it is. So add an if statement to retun Yes or No.

`=IF(COUNTIFS($B$3:$B$4,"<="&B9,$C$3:$C$4,">="&B9)>0,"YES","NO")`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `=IF(OR(AND))` conditions and to set it up a bit manually like this:

```
=IF(OR(
      AND((inspectedDate>=startDate1),inspectedDate<=endDate1)),
      AND((inspectedDate>=startDate2),(inspectedDate<=endDate2))
       ),"Holiday","")
```

- The `AND` part of the formula makes sure that the `inspectedDate` is within a holiday range
- The `OR` part returns `True`, if it is within one of the ranges.